# Capture ID of the Record

Tags: apex, trigger

I am writing a Trigger on Account object to capture and place the id in one field. Whenever the record is inserted or updated it should display the id of the record in ID_of_Record__c field on Account.

I have tried below code but giving error.

```
trigger CaptureID on Account (after insert, after update) {

    List<Account> acclst = new List<Account>();
    for(Account acc:Trigger.new)
    {
        acc.ID_of_Record__c = acc.Id;
        acclst.add(acc);
    }
    update acclst;
}
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Apex trigger CaptureID caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: CaptureID: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only: Trigger.CaptureID: line 6, column 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with Formula field and Workflow. Trigger is not required for this scenario.

Create **formula** field of type **text** and write `ID` in formula editor. Save the field.

OR

You can do it using **workflow** rule. Set field update action and update the field with record ID.

OR

**With Trigger ( Bad code written in the cleanest way, less developers will curse :) )**

```
trigger CaptureID on Account (after insert, before update) {

    List< Account > acclst = new List< Account >();
    for(Account acc:Trigger.new)
    { 
         if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert)
         {
           Account  accnew = new Account (Id = acc.Id);
           accnew. ID_of_Record__c = acc.Id;
           acclst.add(accnew);
         }
         else if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isUpdate)
         {
             acc. ID_of_Record__c = acc.Id;
         }
    }
    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert)
      update acclst;
}
```

Comment: yeah i know by formula field we can achieve easily. But am trying with trigger @Ashwani

Comment: Why would you do it with a trigger? Is this just an exercise to see if it can be done? If so, Trigger.new is read-only in the `after` cycle. If it is for production, then do yourself a favor. Don't use a trigger. Use a formula field. Or, use a workflow field update with a formula to copy the Id value into this field on insert.

Comment: for future purposes am writing trigger. Tell me if there is any way to get id by Trigger.  @Peter

Comment: @Prince Trigger way is also updated.

Comment: @Ashwani when inserting a new record only it is fetching record to the field but not with updation

Comment: @Prince Answer is updated, It will work on update as well.

Comment: Awsome!!. I thought only way to do this by  using a Recursive class. But you made it without recursive class. Thanks @Ashwani

Comment: No update. Id is not updateable so `after update` trigger is pointless in this context. If I was doing this on an updateable field, I would check for change between `Trigger.new[n].My_Field__c` and `Trigger.old[n].MyField__c` and only then set the value.

Answer (score 1):

Ok...I'll answer this with code, just for the sake of it. Consider this a kind of code-golf-with-triggers-in-apex answer.

But why would you do it when you can use a formula field?

In the docs it clearly states that in the `after` state, the sObject instances of `Trigger.new` are read-only. So what you are attempting (calling update on Trigger.new in an after trigger) will fail. The main reason for this is the fundamental problem of calling update on a record that has already been saved/inserted (but not committed) to the DB. Also there is the problem that calling update on a trigger with an update trigger on it creates a race condition where trigger triggers trigger, triggers trigger, ad nauseum, ad governor-limit-exceptium.

But again, why on earth would you bother when a formula field would work, take less time to implement, and not require test code.

That's not to say your trigger can't update the records in the `after` state...you just need a new instance to write to the DB. Then you need a static variable to stop the race condition.

There are many posts and many blogs on how to avoid trigger race conditions. 
Using a [static variable](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24307/how-do-i-control-recursive-triggers-with-static-variables-and-permit-mass-edit-f). Using a [more advanced](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46790/how-to-avoid-recursive-trigger-other-than-the-classic-class-w-static-variable) structure. So look closely at that. I'm not going to waste space here to repeat those examples.

As far as getting the accounts to save, you need to create a list of new Account instances to work with...not just pass the reference to the ones in `Trigger.new`.

```
List<Account> listOfAccountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
for (Account a : Trigger.new){
  //creating the new account instance is key. this decouples the record
  //in the DB from the R.O. instance sitting in trigger.new
  Account newAccountInstance = new Account(Id=a.Id);
  newAccountInstance.ID_of_Record__c = a.Id;
  listOfAccountsToUpdate.add(newAccountInstance);
}
update listOfAccountsToUpdate;
```

Of course, you're going to do this as a formula field in production anyway, so this really is pointless, right?

One final thing...

You can actually skip the possibility of recursion by **not making this an update trigger**. If all you are doing is copying from Id to your custom field, update is superfluous. **Id is not updateable**. Yep, the system will *never* update that Id value, so take out the `after update` and you remove a lot of potential pain for yourself, future developers, and your users.

But I don't want you to vote for my answer. So please, please, pretty please, don't check it as correct. Check formula field answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

ok after @Peter, @Ashwani suggestions and codes. I got my answer
Here for updation I used Recursvice class with recursive class

**Recursive Class**

```
public class RecursiveClsForCaptureIDTrigger {

     private static boolean run = true;
     public static boolean runOnce(){
       if(run)
       {
         run=false;
         return true;
       }
       else
       {
        return run;
       }
    }
}
```

Trigger for update and insert

```
trigger CaptureID on Account (after insert, after update) {

    List<Account> acclst = new List<Account>();
    for(Account acc:Trigger.new)
    { 
         Account  accnew = new Account (Id = acc.Id);
         accnew.ID_of_Record__c = acc.Id;
         acclst.add(accnew);
    }
    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert){
        update acclst;
    }      
    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){
        if(RecursiveClsForCaptureIDTrigger.runOnce())
        {
            update acclst;
        }
    }

}
```